# Black screen when playing a movie in VLC player in Kubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, vlc, video-player, avi

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44425/black-screen-when-playing-a-movie-in-vlc-player-just-the-sound-is-enabled). In my situation, my AVI files will play correctly in other installed players -- but not in VLC. Unfortunately, I need frame-by-frame controls, and VLC is the only player I have installed that offers that feature. But VLC won't always play my AVI files. It seems to depend on the recording options (such as HD or standard def and frame rate), although I'm not entirely sure why some play and some don't.

Given that some other players on my system play these files, can I assume I have all the drivers needed? The players that work include MPlayer and Dragon player. Everything is fine in those players. And VLC ***sometimes*** plays AVI video files. (The files it won't play are played by the other players, so I believe my system has all the codecs required.)

When I installed Kubuntu I installed these packages:

```
sudo apt-get --yes install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu

sudo apt-get install w64codecs libdvdcss2 non-free-codecs ffmpeg libxine1-ffmpeg gxine mencoder libmpcdec6 libquicktime2 libmp4v2-2 flac faac faad sox ffmpeg2theora libmpeg2-4 uudeview flac libmpeg3-1 mpeg3-utils mpegdemux liba52-dev mpeg2dec vorbis-tools id3v2 mpg123 libflac++6 ffmpeg totem-mozilla icedax tagtool easytag id3tool lame libmad0 libjpeg-progs kubuntu-restricted-extras libdvdread4
```

(Do I need all those?)

These were ***not*** installed:

```
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was as simple as this:

```
$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install kubuntu-restricted-extras
```

VLC works now! :)

Answer (score 0):

A little late on the issue, but in my case VLC was failing to embed video output window into the main window (I've concluded that from observing a small window appearing with video displayed right after quitting the player while the video was playing). So after switching *off*

```
Tools > Preferences > All > Video > Embedded video
```

checkbox and restarting VLC the video played with HW acceleration, but in a separate window.

Installing/uninstalling **kubuntu-restricted-extras** had no effect, though I've had **ubuntu-restricted-extras** installed all along.

On another note, mpv was able to display the same video from the box.

Comment: As this question is over 10 years old it is probably of no use to try and offer an answer that is for a different version of VLC.